# sliceした属性を変数にしてupdate_allの引数に渡したいのですが、表記方法がわからず困っています

Tags: ruby-on-rails

下記コードのようにFooオブジェクトからsliceで属性を指定して、同じ属性名をもつbarの値を一括でupdateしたいのですが、`update_all`で指定する`attribute`をどのように書けばよいかわからず、試行錯誤しましたが、うまい方法が見つからずアドバイスを頂ければ幸いです。

```
foo = Foo.first
bar = Bar.where(hoge: hoge) # ActiveRecord::Relation

foo.attributes.slice('a','b','c').each do |attribute, value|
  bar.update_all(attribute: value) # この部分の書き方がわからないです...
end
```

Answer (score 2):

`update_attributes`を使ってはどうでしょうか？

```
foo = Foo.first
bars = Bar.where(hoge: hoge) # ActiveRecord::Relation

bars.each{|bar| bar.update_attributes(foo.attributes.slice('a','b','c')) }
```

Comment: おお、ありがとうございます！  
`update_attributes`を使えばよかったのですね...  
すごく勉強になりました！ありがとうございます！